# SQL query issue No data is showing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

here is my result set but when i am doing query on the result set then no data is coming but i am not being able to understand what is the wrong in my query.

```
call Start         Caller       direction Is_Internal continuation call duration       party1name
------------------ ------------ --------- ----------- ------------ ------------------ -----------------
1/15/2014 8:47     346241552    I         0           0            0:00:18             VM Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 9:56     252621028    I         0           0            0:00:17             Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 9:58     252621028    I         0           0            0:00:17             Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 9:01     252621028    I         0           1            0:00:08             Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 9:01     252621028    I         0           0            0:01:57             Coen
1/15/2014 9:06     302          O         0           0            0:01:53             Coen
1/15/2014 9:07     306          O         0           0            0:01:33             koos de Bruijn
1/15/2014 9:11     644686793    I         0           0            0:00:08             VM Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 9:11     644686793    I         0           0            0:01:46             Coen
1/15/2014 9:27     306          O         0           0            0:00:43             koos de Bruijn
1/15/2014 9:25     302          O         0           0            0:06:46             Coen
1/15/2014 9:46     455426194    I         0           1            0:00:07             VM Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 9:46     455426194    I         0           0            0:00:50             Coen
1/15/2014 9:57     725716251    I         0           1            0:00:10             VM Kanaal 1
1/15/2014 10:00    0            I         O           1            0:00:00             Voicemail
```

my query is here

```
SELECT Convert(varchar,[call Start],101) Date,[Caller] [Phone No], Count(*) [Total Incomming calls]  FROM tridip
 where direction='I' and 
CAST([call Start] AS datetime) >= CONVERT(datetime,'09:00:00') and 
CAST([call Start] AS datetime) <= CONVERT(datetime,'17:30:00') 
AND Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0 AND
CONVERT(datetime,CAST([call duration] AS DATETIME),108) <> CAST('00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 
and  party1name not in ('Voice Mail') and party1name not like 'VM %' 
and party1name not like 'Line%'  
group by [Caller],Convert(varchar,[call Start],101)
```

just tell me what is wrong my query. it should show date & phone number and count may be 1 or more than 1. please guide me what to alter.

at the second row there is phone no 252621028 which is repeated and it's count should be greater than 1.

thanks

### UPDATE

i figured out the problem and rectified sql as follow

```
SELECT [Caller] [Phone No], Count(*) [Total Incomming calls]  FROM tridip
 where direction='I' and 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,[call Start],108) >= '09:00:00' and 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,[call Start],108) <= '17:30:00' 
AND Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0 AND
[call duration] <> '00:00:00'
and  party1name not in ('Voice Mail') and party1name not like 'VM %' 
and party1name not like 'Line%' and [Caller]>0
group by [Caller]
```

Comment: Your two comparisions (the first is `CAST([call Start] AS datetime) >= CONVERT(datetime,'09:00:00')`) can never match, and therefore there can never be any rows returned. The first is a full datetime, the second is a time only. You'll need to convert them both to compatible types and then compare them.

Comment: @KenWhite - I believe it's the second compression which would fail, not the first once.

Comment: @Suyash: I think there are several comparisons which would fail. I figured getting Thomas started would be enough, and he could figure out the rest himself. (And your answer points out just exactly what I stated in my comment. The comparison of `CAST [Call Start]` to a datetime can never match the value of `CONVERT datetime` with just a timestamp.)

Answer (score 5):

You are not getting results most probably because of this condition -

`CAST([call Start] AS datetime) <= CONVERT(datetime,'17:30:00')`

**Reason** -

**Try this -**

`SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'17:30:00')`

**The result is -** `1900-01-01 17:30:00.000`

I believe none of your records have [call start] time less than this and hence no results.

Are your trying to get all the records between 2 times ?

Comment: so what is your suggestion. i was comparing time from datetime field. suggest something right.

Comment: @Thomas - I was away for a bit, but that worked out better for you that you were able to figure it out. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

As has been previously mentioned, you are getting a DateTime with the value of `1900-01-01 09:00`, which is obviously lower than any of your dates.

You can also use the `DATEPART` function of SQL Server to compare dates and times easier:

```
where     direction='I'
and       DATEPART(hour, CAST([call Start] AS datetime)) >= 9
and       DATEPART(hour, CAST([call Start] AS datetime)) <= 17
```

(You will need to modify this slightly to work for being before 17:30, but it gives you the general idea).